# Handling click event for custom view inside fragment's listview

Tags: android, listview, interface, fragment, adapter

I have a listview inside fragment in android. What I need is to handle click event in custom view. I have custom BaseAdapter.

**What I solved**

I created a **Interface** inside adapter and implement in fragment. And in **onClickListener** for button, **I cast fragment that is passed from constructor and call the method.**

My Question is How can I get Parent Fragment from my Adapter. I don't want to pass fragment from constructor. I searched a lot and I don't see anything. Any reference can help me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass fragment through constructor then you will pass an instance of activity for inflating the custom view. Add a method in the activity that will return your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you do not like to pass the fragment as listener to adapter.

But I assume in your BaseAdapter you should have the Activity context. If assumption is correct, you may do:

```
((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
```

to get the corresponding fragment.